# how to use C# enum list in typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, enums

This is my enum list class in C#

```
   namespace MyProject.MyName
    {
   public enum MyNameList
     {
    [Description("NameOne")]
    NameOne,

    [Description("NameTwo")]
    NameTwo,

    [Description("NameThree")]
    NameThree
        }
      }
```

And this is how I use this enum list inside C# `.cshtml` razor and javascript

```
    @using MyProject.MyName
     ....
     ....
     <script>
          ..
          ..
      if (result.data == @((int)MyNameList.NameOne))
          ..
          ..
     </script>
```

Now I have to write this (javascript) code in Typescript and how can I use my Enum list `MyNameList` inside Typescript ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new typescript definition file, for example, **nameList.d.ts**

```
export enum MyNameList
{
    NameOne,
    NameTwo,
    NameThree
}
```

Inside Typescript file, import like this

```
import { MyNameList } from "./nameList";
```

And now you can use those enum list inside typescript like

```
MyNameList.NameOne
```

Answer (score 1):

The javascript is executed on the local browser.  You would not be able to use Enum directly there.

You can return the Enum value as a part of response and then compare the enum value in JS.

You can add enum in typescript and then use it to compare with the response fields.

```
enum Direction {
    Up = "UP",
    Down = "DOWN",
    Left = "LEFT",
    Right = "RIGHT",
}
```

Comment: do I have to create new enum list for Typescript ?? can I map to C# enum list ??

Comment: @StevenSann You cannot use C# code in typescript.  This is becuase your server side code is never sent in the response to browser.   You will have to create new Enum.  If your original enum changes then typescript enum should also be changed.